P4 switch (stream), but only partially
I have two streams. They are both children development streams of a parent mainline stream that contains two folders, a smaller (let's say 400GB) and a larger (let's say 2TB) folder.
I currently have one of them bound in a workspace, however, I have only synced the smaller folder, the larger one does not exist on my disk.
The problem is, if I do p4 switch <other_stream>, p4 will iterate through all files in the large folder (since it doesn't exist on my disk, but does exist in the stream I'm switching to) and try to sync them. The reconcile bit of the command also takes a lot of time.
I know that p4 switch does p4 reconcile and p4 sync of some form in the background, but I couldn't find info on what exactly.
Running p4 switch -Rn --no-sync <other_stream> does complete very quickly, but I still have to make sure the versions of the files matches the version in the stream.
I tried doing p4 reconcile or p4 reconcile -k, but it was painfully slow. When I ran p4 switch <other_stream> originally, before it started sifting through the larger folder, it ran reconcile over the smaller one in mere seconds. But I don't know which flags it used internally.
All in all, how do I switch stream in perforce while excluding one or more folders in the process of switching (because I don't have the files synced locally)?

The easiest option to avoid ever syncing the big folder is to modify your child streams so that they only include the small folder.  Just specify the folder in your Paths (replacing the default ... which is everything from the parent):
Parent: //stream/main
Paths:
    share small_folder/...

If you want to map the big folder in your stream but avoid ever syncing it (which generally defeats the purpose of having it mapped in the stream), you'll need to constantly remember to use the --no-sync option on switch, and p4 sync while specifying the folder path, e.g.:
p4 switch -Rn --no-sync other-stream
p4 sync small_folder/...

Simply specifying the desired small_folder in your stream definition(s) avoids the problem entirely, since then syncing the entire stream will only sync that folder.
Note that if you do this before populating the stream, you can also avoid populating (branching) all those unwanted files!  (Since your streams have already been populated, the extra branched files will hang around in the depot, but modifying the stream after the fact will at least make sure that they never get synced to your workspace or integrated with the mainline.)
